# Generic baseclass with generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, radix

I want to create a baseclass, which has a few default methods. This baseclass should use a generic interface.

Is this possible? (because code-example below doesn't compile, the problem lies within T1,T2,T3 -> first line)

```
public abstract class ServiceBase<T> where T: IService<T1,T2,T3>
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<T3> Search(T1 query);

    public abstract T3 Add(T2 input);

    public bool Monitor()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The reason I want to use is, is for a service, I can type:

```
public class WhatEverService : ServiceBase<IWhatEverService>
```

With IWhatEverService inheriting from IService<T1,T2,T3> (with T1,T2,T3 some different types)

FYI:

```
public interface IWhatEverService: IService<WhatEverType1, WhatEverType2, WhatEverType3>
```

Comment: Does anyone know to do this without passing 4 parameters?

Answer (score 2):

You have not told compiler what T1, T2 and T3 are and it is not able to infer these types from usage.

```
public abstract class ServiceBase<T,T1,T2,T3> where T : IService<T1,T2,T3>
```

Comment: That compiles indeed, but in that case, I need to inherit from ServiceBase<IWhatEverService, type1, type2, type3>. The point is the 3 types are already defined inside IWhatEverService

Comment: On the `IService<T1,T2,T3>` part you tell compiler that the generic `IService` interface will have generic arguments of type T1, T2 and T3. But you have not told compiler what T1, T2, and T3 are. The only way telling compiler "don't worry about T1, T2, T3" is declaring them along with the class name.